# Interpreting the power rating of the refrigerator

Tags: power, watts, power-consumption

My refrigerator is rated as 130W of power. I need to know how to interpret this. Does that mean if the compressor works for a whole hour then only it consumes 130W? Or is 130W the average power considering that the compressor will be sleeping for most of the time? The refrigerator is from LG electronics.

Comment: Such questions about consumer products not involving electronic design are off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

130W continuous power draw would be a huge fridge (if it is any good at its job). For example, my fridge does 25W on average over 24hr and has a capacity of approx. 200 liters cooling area + 94 liters fridge area.

A fridge in Europe comes with an energy label that specifies its consumption / power-hungry'ness, if you search for your exact type on Internet you'll find these specs for your fridge too.

[image]

Amongst other things the label will specify the power use per year. In my case 219kWh/year. So if there are:

- 1000 Wh in a 1kWh
- 365 days in a year
- 24 hours in a day

Then the average power equals:

\$P_{avg} = \dfrac{219 × 1000}{365×24} = \boxed{25\text{W}}\$

The type plate however states 90W. This is maximum power when the compressor is running and probably when the lighting is turned on.

The type plate also states 0.7A, which would come to 230V × 0.7A = 161VA. Notice these are VA, not W! The higher current probably be drawn during compressor start up, and probably has some safety headroom too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this comes from the nameplate label on the refrigerator, it is the maximum continuous power that the device can consume.  In other words, it is the power consumed with the compressor running, condenser and evaporator fans running, fridge light on, etc. It is not the power consumed when the compressor/fans are starting (higher peak current), nor is it any sort of long-term average draw.

If you step back and think about it, there's no way it could be anything other than this - the average power consumption of a refrigerator will be a function of the compressor duty cycle.  The compressor duty cycle will be dependent on factors that vary wildly between use cases - Is the fridge in 0C ambient or 50C ambient?  Was the door left open?

New refrigerators come with an efficiency sticker that compares annual energy consumption for a particular model to models of a similar size and with similar features.  This is as close as you'll get to a comparison of average power consumption, and it's only going to be relative to other models, not absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to contact the manufacturer (or read the power rating information in more depth).

There are many ways to measure the power draw of an appliance, and a number of standards for providing ratings as such. We can't give you more information without knowing which method the manufacturer has used.

---

For what it's worth, I would **guess** that that is an average power rating.