# Connecting multiple Raspberry Pis to the same power

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a smart fridge.

In the fridge, I have 4 shelves.  Each shelf has a Raspberry Pi 4. I don't want a mess of cables in the fridge. Because of that, I want to make a power module (or use anadapter) to connect all the Raspberry Pi power cabled.

Each Raspberry Pi 4 needs 5V and 3A. What would you recommend for this?

Comment: Before you continue thinking how to wire it, have you noticed that you are essentially putting a 60W heating source inside the fridge, and that heat needs to be constantly removed by the fridge cooling system?

Comment: I'm thinking of placing the power module or adapter somewhere in the upper part of the fridge, not the cold part.

Comment: it does not matter. It's the Raspberry Pis that are the 60W heating element inside your fridge.

Answer (score 5):

To directly answer your question, "all" you need to run four pis in parallel is a power supply that can deliver the required current (likely >12A) at 5VDC – although note that the consumption of each pi does [vary quite a lot.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) There are many such consumer products for USB that can do that (e.g. [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082SNBJBL), not that I recommend it) or you could go whole-hog and buy a proper independent power supply and connect each pi to it independently. That said, I believe that the idle current of a pi is around 575 mA, so it really depends on what you are doing with them all as to how much you need a higher current rail.

However, I'd strongly recommend not running four separate raspberry pis in a fridge – I don't know how you've got them set up, but it's likely you could get by with one pi, outside of the fridge, and the sensor or your device inside the fridge. There are several advantages to doing this:

1. A fridge is a cold environment and can be a humid one (think of putting a bowl of soup in there). This is below the dew point and water will condense on nearby exposed surfaces. Unless you've put each pi in an ingress-protected sealed environment, ideally with dry air, this means the board. This can cause shorts and failures of the pi, as well as potentially leading to likely-undesired electrolytic reactions with other objects inside your fridge if they should come in contact with a conductor.
2. Four pis will generate a steady and significant amount of heat (in the context of a fridge), as the supposed 12A*5V=60W load they will draw in total will increase the load on the compressor on the back of the fridge – for context, [a typical EU fridge draws around 25 W averaged over a year once cool](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68872/interpreting-the-power-rating-of-the-refrigerator). This will both increase electricity bills (dramatically) and may lead to the temperature inside rising, causing food to spoil. Whether or not the fridge will be able to cope with this continuous heat load depends on it -- they are mostly designed to fight thermal diffusion, not extract continuously generated heat.
3. The SD card and other components in each pi may either underperform or fail more at low temperatures or with condensing water.

By placing sensor(s) inside and the pi outside you can:

1. Use sensors with a datasheet that specifies that they will work in the fridge as an operating environment
2. Put the heat-generating pis outside of the fridge, prolonging its life and decreasing power consumption
3. Reduce the possibility that your experiment inadvertently damages food.